# What components should be "containerized" - Docker

Tags: docker

I am exploring use of containers in a new application and have looked at a fair amount of content and created a sandbox environment to explore docker and containers. My struggle is more an understanding what components needs to be containerized individually vs bundling multiple components into my own container. And what points to consider when architecting this?
Example:
I am building a python back end service to be executed via webservice call.
The service would interact with both Mongo DB, and RabbitMQ.

My questions are:
Should I run individual OS container (EG Ubuntu), Python Container, MongoDB Container, Rabbit MQ container etc? Combined they all form part of my application and by decoupling everything I have the ability to scale individually?

How would I be able to bundle/link these for deployment without losing the benefits of decoupling/decomposing into individual containers

Is an OS and python container actually required as this will all be running on an OS with python anyways?

Would love to see how people have approached this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker's philosophy: using microservices in containers. The term "`Microservice Architecture`" has sprung up over the last few years to describe a particular way of designing software applications as suites of `independently deployable services`.

Some advantages of `microservices architecture` are:

- Easier upgrade management
- Eliminates long-term commitment to a single technology stack
- Improved fault isolation
- Makes it easier for a new developer to understand the functionality of a service
- Improved Security
- ...

> Should I run individual OS container (EG Ubuntu), Python Container,
>   MongoDB Container, Rabbit MQ container etc? Combined they all form
>   part of my application and by decoupling everything I have the ability
>   to scale individually?

You dont need an individual OS ontainer. Each container will use Docker host's kernel, and will contain only binaries required, python binaries for example.

So you will have, a `python` container for you python service, `MongoDB` container and `RabbitMQ` container.

> How would I be able to bundle/link these for deployment without losing
>   the benefits of decoupling/decomposing into individual containers?

For deployments, You will use dockerfiles + docker-compose file. Dockerfiles include instructions to create a docker image. If you are just using official library images, you don't need dockerfiles.

`docker-compose` will help you orchestrate the container builds (from docker files), start ups, Creating required networks, Mounting required volumes and etc.

Comment: great response - Thank you